# iOS UI is getting blocked on refresh button clicked while downloading JSon Data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning How to parse JSON and load it in tableview while my internet is working the data  is get parsed and loaded in table correctly but when i turn off my internet and refresh my table view my UI get stuck on same screen with previous JSON data and crashes after some time
following is how i implemented it..
on my table view controller i define this method which is getting called on refresh button click.

```
- (IBAction) reloadJasonData:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray * jsonArray= [DownloadJsonData getJsonArray];

    if(! jsonArray)
    {
        UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error!!" message:@" Please Check the Internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [errorAlert show];

}
else
{
    NSSortDescriptor * sortDescripter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"location" ascending:YES];
    NSArray * discriptorArray = @[sortDescripter];
    self.sortedJsonArray = [jsonArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:discriptorArray];

    self.arrayOfLinks = [self.sortedJsonArray valueForKey:@"link"];
    self.arrayOfLocations = [self.sortedJsonArray valueForKey:@"location"];

    self.arrayOfDates = [self.sortedJsonArray valueForKey:@"date_time"];
    NSLog(@"Count of cities in fetch data:  %d",[self.sortedJsonArray count]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

in other class i have define class method to download JSON data

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getJsonArray
{
    NSError * error;
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:httpURL];
    NSMutableArray * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    return json;
}
```

the error message shows only when my internet connection is not active and i click on refresh button, but once the data is displayed into table and i shout down my internet and click on refresh button again my UI get stuck..

I hope i have explained my problem in well manner so can any body help me to figure it out where did i messed it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted below?

Comment: i am still working on it..i just started learning iOS and objective c so i need little bit time to understand things..plus i haven't yet fully understood delegates..so i have to spend some time with that also..but thanks for guiding me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are accessing your data from internet using main thread that's why your UI get stuck. You should access any remote data using secondary thread.

Write this code inside your getJsonArray class

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:httpURL];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error && data!=nil)
           //call a delegate to send the data to your page from where it was called
        else
          //show alert that an error has occurred during downloading data from net.
    }];
```

Then use delegate to tell the main page that the data has been downloaded and then there on delegate method reload your tableView in main thread.